# How to insert a document with a sub-document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I'm trying to insert a document with a sub-document.

When I enter my data, I keep getting a syntax error stating I am missing a '}'. However, I can't see where it is missing. I would really appreciate some feedback! Thank you!

```
db.inspections.insert({"id": "20032-2020-ACME", "certificate_number": "9998888", "business_name": "ACME Explosives", "date": date(), "result": "Business Padlocked", "sector": "Explosive Retail Dealer-999", "address": { "number->1721" : "street->Boom Road" : "city->BRONX" : "zip->10463" }})
```

[image]

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can paste the `db.inspections.insert` code here :)

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe Sorry about that! I posted a picture. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the address object is not a valid JSON (`"address": { "number->1721" : "street->Boom Road" : "city->BRONX" : "zip->10463" }`). It should be like `"address": {"number": 1721, "street": "Boom Road" ....}`

Comment: @Vishnu thank you!! That fixed it! One additional question. I now get a uncaught exception about my date() function. Can I not use this function to get the current date?

Comment: You can use the `new Date()` instead. This will provide the ISODate in UTC